# Parameter of Conditional Gaussian Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, autoencoders

I'd like to understand how to determine the parameter of **conditional gaussian distribution**. Following is the network architecture of [**VUNET**](https://compvis.github.io/vunet/images/vunet.pdf) which learns the conditional gaussian distribution $q(z|x, \hat y)$ of **appearance of human($z$)** upon given two conditional inputs **skeleton of body pose** **and groundTruth image($x$)** of 128x128 resolution image

[image: vunet architecture]

I don't understand how $2\times2\times256$ vector and 
$1\times1$ vector can characterize  $q(z|x, \hat y)$. Any advice to understand this point clearly?

Comment: I think the blue lines represent dense connections to $q(z|x,\hat{y})$ and $p(z|\hat{y})$, which can then consist of any number of latent dimensions.

Comment: @FransRodenburg so do you mean even blue lanes represents a dense-layers that contains operations in it?

Comment: Yes, from my limited experience with VAEs, I believe that is how the latent distribution is learned. See for example the $\textsf{R}$ Keras example on VAEs (https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/variational_autoencoder_deconv.html): `z_mean` and `z_log_var` are coded as a dense layer, taking last layer of the encoder as input.

Comment: @FransRodenburg so you are saying: 
exact number of parameters doesn't matter but we just use any number of latent variable as our own discretion?

Comment: I tried to find the number of nodes used in the latent part in the paper, but I could not find it. In the example I gave above, 2 are used (`latent_dim`), but in principle it should work with a different number as well.

Comment: @FransRodenburg more fundamental question is, how is it irrelevant to fit the exact number of parameters of 3 multi-variable gaussian distribution? I mean, then at least some what at certain point of layer-output, should't it be matched to the exact number of parameters of 3 multi-variable gaussian distribution?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is irrelevant, as you are changing your model complexity. Although I'm not sure I understand your reply, keep in mind that while you are learning a latent distribution with a fixed number of parameters (mean and variance in case of a Gaussian), you can still learn a multivariate distribution (i.e. $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$) that can in principle have any number of dimensions.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2900231/59351. Please decide which site you want this question on, & delete it from the other. (It can be moved later if you don't get answers.)